# MooTools JSONP Invalid label

Tags: ajax, json, mootools, jsonp

Struck on getting my data to display on the page, keep getting hung up on a "Invalid label" Error

Current.js (MooTools)

```
    new Request.JSONP({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://somesite.com?needwhat=58b0e',
        evalScripts:false,
        evalResponse:false,
        onSuccess:function(responseTree, responseElements, responseHTML, responseJavaScript)
        {
            $('#gallery').set('html',responseHTML);
            eval(responseJavaScript);
        }
    }).send();
```

And what I'm trying to retrieve from the server

```
    {
     "id": "58b0e",
     "items": [
    {
        "title": "Some Title..."
    }
   ]}
```

Comment: At first glance, it looks like that comma at the end of your "title" line in JSON shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right. I remember it was hard to get my head around JSONP initially so i will try to explain it as best as I can and in a way that may be helpful to others as well...

Before you can understand the error, you need to consider the fundamental difference between the mootools Request.JSON and Request.JSONP classes.

Though you may consider them to be the same with the slight difference of same origin policy being removed from JSONP, they are not at all similar and the only common things they share are: they both return an object and share the same namespace (Request.)

Other than that, they couldn't be more different. Request.JSONP extends the default XHR class (Request) as can only run within the same origin domain/subdomain and protocol. It will expect the server to return a JSON string back, which it can parse/eval and convert into an object.

The string passed on will look similar to the one you have sent, or more complicated, whatever. Basic stuff.

Where XHR fails is fetching data from *elsewhere*. One of the only ways you can import data from another domain is via javascript. There is no restriction on the origin of a script source. The problem for JSONP from a server to client is that it needs to pass *specific* data back to your callee function and scope (in this case, Request.JSONP). Embedding a script is not enough, it needs to *pass* the data.

Basically, JSONP works by means of defining a function within the global scope, eg:

`window.mycallback = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
};`

it then typically requests the remote end to 'wrap' the data in a function called `mycallback`, something that you will often see in any and all APIs for JSONP services.

The embed script then looks like (eg):

`http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/shitmydadsays.json?callback=mycallback`

what twitter will create is a file with this content:

```
mycallback({"listed_count":56509,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a1.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/150162853\/desk-final.jpg","protected":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","name":"Justin","following":false,"followers_count":2743626,"id_str":"62581962","notifications":false,"utc_offset":-28800,"profile_background_color":"9AE4E8","description":"I'm 29. I live with my 74-year-old dad. He is awesome. I just write down shit that he says","default_profile_image":false,"statuses_count":144,"verified":false,"profile_background_tile":false,"profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/150162853\/desk-final.jpg","favourites_count":0,"location":"","show_all_inline_media":false,"contributors_enabled":false,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDFFCC","screen_name":"shitmydadsays","status":{"retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"id_str":"114026815026249728","contributors":null,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"favorited":false,"truncated":false,"source":"web","place":null,"geo":null,"retweet_count":"100+","in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"id":114026815026249728,"coordinates":null,"text":"\"Bullshit. Don't pretend you don't care about your birthday. It's like watching a hooker pretend she's out for a walk when cops drive by.\"","created_at":"Wed Sep 14 17:24:45 +0000 2011"},"is_translator":false,"url":"http:\/\/www.twitter.com\/justin_halpern","default_profile":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)","friends_count":1,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"BDDCAD","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/362705903\/dad_normal.jpg","lang":"en","geo_enabled":false,"profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/362705903\/dad_normal.jpg","id":62581962,"created_at":"Mon Aug 03 18:20:34 +0000 2009","profile_text_color":"333333"});
```

what this really does is, here's your data object, passed as an argument to your function myfunction.

myfunction's first argument then is your JSON object.

Mootools Request.JSONP deals with the request mapping etc but it needs the remote end to be able to work with the callback= parameter and wrap all data in it. If it does not support it, the remote service is NOT suitable for JSONP.

When using Request.JSONP, the above url will actually automatically go out as:

http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show/shitmydadsays.json?callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_0

MooTools will map a `listener` function into the Request.JSONP.request_map object, but you can override the callback locally and remotely as well.

The error you have is the same if you just try to run this code:

```
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

On its own, it's not valid javascript and will trigger `SyntaxError: invalid label`. Get a wrapper func!